# Format axis labels from scale_y_time() in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to figure out how to manipulate the axis labels that are produced when using `scale_y_time()` in ggplot2. For example, I would like to change the y-axis label produced by the code below to be just "minutes and seconds" (`"%M:%S"`)

Here is a simple example of the kind of plot I am making, with data that represents a "starting point" (`start`) and "ending point" (`end`) and time tag in seconds that goes with each starting point (`time`).

```
library(tidyverse)

start <- seq(1, 105, 5)
end <- seq(3, 103, 5)
time = seq(0, 360, 18)

dat <- data.frame(start, end, time)

ggplot(dat) + 
  geom_segment(aes(x = start, y = time, xend = end, yend = time)) +
  scale_y_time()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`+ scale_y_time(labels = function(t) strftime(t, "%M:%S"))` should yield:

[image]